# How do i connect a python script to my discord account via requests? I can't use a discord.py bot cause they cant Interact with another discord bot

Tags: python, html, url, discord, request

so i made this little py script,i want to to send this command to my discord server, but
this dosn't work, so like just nothing happens

```
import requests
url="https://discord.com/api/v9/interactions"

auth={
"authorization": "XXX"
}
msg={
     "data":"/imagine prompt: very yellow banana"
}
requests.post(url,headers=auth,json=msg)
```

somebody know what i make wrong here?
*i got the url's using the inspector on the discord browser.

this does, but it just send the command as message.

```
import requests
url="https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/XXX/messages"

auth={
"authorization": "XXX"
}
msg={
     "content":"/imagine prompt: very yellow banana"
}
requests.post(url,headers=auth,json=msg)
```

Comment: Use `discord.py` instead of doing HTTP requests.

Comment: Please read [ask]. _Specifically_, what does "doesn't work" mean?

Answer (score 0):

There is discord.py that might fit your need.

Discord.py - https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

HTTP requests isn't an option to interact with discord.

Comment: Unfortunately a discord bot can’t interact with the mid journey bot, so I need to find a work around